# What are the main factors that define what a quality design of a system is?

Tags: oop, software-quality

What do you consider to be the main factors in a quality design of a system?

Following the GRASP Patterns (low coupling / high cohesion, protected variations, etc). What more?

Comment: I am not sure what CW stands for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bob Martin's [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) is what I'd recommend.

Comment: I think that is really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you could also look into:

DRY,
YAGINI,
Rigidity,
Fragility,
Viscosity,
Immobility.

You can refer [here](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/Principles_and_Patterns.pdf) for explanation of some of them.